# How do I kill the dragon in the moon?

Tags: nintendo-ds, final-fantasy-4

I'm trying to get all the pieces of the crystal armor in the dungeon in the moon, but there's a red dragon in a box that kills me with "Thermal Ray" that makes something like 2k of damage to my party.

Any advice on how fight it?

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution. I have to cast slow and berserk on it, so that it can't use "thermal ray".

It was so obvious... How do I forgot?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Try with casting reflect on your party, I played it very long time ago so I cannot be sure about it.
However... Great game ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Silver_Dragon_%28Final_Fantasy_IV%29
This link says the best method is to just hack away at it.

You should probably level up a bit before this fight if you're getting hit that badly!

Comment: Thank you for the link and the reference, although the dragons is in a box with the last piece of the crystal armor, I can't escape nor use teleport. 

I'm 82 so I don't really know which level I should reach.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that people just love using magic in every single battle. If I remember correctly, this monster reacts with Thermal Ray every time you use magic on him, if you don't it's really easy and it's attacks are mostly harmless.